# React-Router confused about my lifecycle router

Tags: react-router

After checking out [this react-router tutorial](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md), I tried to integrate what I learned here into my project.

My scenario is similar to the number 2 from the tutorial, except that when the user enters `/`, I want to fetch an api and redirect to the first category comming from the api that looks like this `[{'category':'electronics', 'items':[{..}],..},..]`

my router looks like this

```
import RoutaZ from 'Routes.js';
...

<Router history={hashHistory}>
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to={RoutaZ.state.data[0].name} />
  <Route path=":category" components={Container, SideNavigation} />
 </Route>
```

my Routes.js looks like this

```
let Routes = React.createClass({
 getInitialState () {
  return {
   data: null
  }
 },

componentDidMount() {
 var self = this;
 fetchData().then(function(results){
  self.setState({data: results.data});
 })
},

render() {
/* want to return the the first category from api */
  return this.state.data[0].name 
 }
});
```

In the router, `RoutaZ.state.data[0].name` returns undefined because the initial state is null. If I set the initial state to [{'category':'hello',...}], it returns hello and redirects to the hello page as expected. What can I do to redirect after the db is fetched?

1) How can I use `onEnter` from react-router with my current config?

2) How and where can I set a parent component to my router handle all the fetching and pass it to the router as a child?

---

**EDIT:** This is just a little part of my application,which is finished but I only have this redirect issue. I know that I can use redux-saga but all my application is already done and would have to redo it completely which I cannot afford.

1- I tried using `onEnter` but don't know where I should place it.

2-Somewhere in my application is fetched data from the parent component and gave it as props to the child and the child received the data from the api.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I had to push the results when the component mounted

```
componentDidMount() {
 var self = this;
 fetchData().then(function(results){
  router.push(results.data[0].category);
 })
},
```